# cmake add-custom-target doesn't create a target

Tags: cmake

I want to build a package that contains a list of files (configuration files that my main task uses). So I am adding these in my CMakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_target(my-configs)

install(
FILES
  file1.cfg
DESTINATION data/task
COMPONENT my-configs
EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

...
```

But when I run :

`make -C ../cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_RelWithDebInfo/task/ my-configs`

I get :

```
make: Entering directory '/development/cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_RelWithDebInfo/task'
make: *** No rule to make target 'my-configs'.  Stop.
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the above create the target?

**EDIT**

This component doesn't do anything apart from copying files into the specified location. In that case, do I need a `custom_target` at all?

Or could I just go ahead and do `cmake install`? If I do install I see :

```
cd ../cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_RelWithDebInfo && DESTDIR=../../cmake-install/linux_64_static_make_RelWithDebInfo cmake -DCOMPONENT=my_configs -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Install component: "my_configs"
```

but nothing gets installed in the DESTDIR as expected - which is why I thought I needed a target so I can regenerate the cmake-build tree? Otherwise how will it know about the new component?

Comment: Is directory `../cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_RelWithDebInfo/task/` the one which has been used as **build directory** when configure the project (with `cmake`)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: "... but nothing gets installed in the DESTDIR as expected" - In `CMakeLists.txt` you define a component with name `my-configs` (with **dash**), but try to install a component with name `my_configs` (with **underscore**).

Comment: In CMake **components** names have nothing common with the **targets** names. If you want to create a target which perform installation, specify appropriate COMMAND for that target. E.g. `add_custom_target(my-configs COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --install . --component my_configs)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, I have spent that hours and didn't notice the typo. So am I wrong in think if I add this component it doesn't necessarily need to have a custom_target. I only want to install those as part of `cmake install` so in that case I wouldn't even need a target right?

Answer (score 0):

One use case for `add_custom_target()` can be like a .PHONY target in a Makefile.

You need to add dependencies to your custom target so that CMake knows how to fill the order. Here some examples:

```
add_custom_target(libs DEPENDS library_1 library_2 ...)
```

So now you have a target `libs` that will build your set of libraries when you specify that target to be built or some other target depends on `libs` to be built.

Another example:

```
add_custom_target(unmount_server COMMAND "umount /mnt/deployment")
```

This would provide a target that would unmount a server drive. Very much a non-portable operation as I have written it.

Comment: But this component doesn't do anything apart from copying files into the specified location. In that case, do I need a `custom_target` at all?